# How to recover from infinite reboot loops in NodeMCU?

Tags: loops, reboot

My NodeMCU program has gone in to infinite reboot loop.

My code is functionally working but any action I try to do, e.g. `file.remove("init.lua")` or even just `=node.heap()`, it panics and reboots saying: `PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (not enough memory)`.

Because of this, I'm not able to change any code or delete `init.lua` to stop automatic code execution.

How do I recover?

Comment: Don’t use a init-file in the development phase. Name it init_start.lua or similiar and use the dofile-command to execute it manually. As soon as your development is done and everthing is working, you can rename it and make use of the automatic execution.

Comment: I was following such, but I wrote init.lua for standalone testing and now I'm locked out :(

Answer (score 7):

I tried re-flashing another version of NodeMCU, but it started emitting garbage in serial port.

Then, I recalled that NodeMCU had two extra files: `blank.bin` and `esp_init_data_default.bin`.

I flashed them at `0x7E000` and `0x7C000` respectively.

They are also available as `INTERNAL://BLANK` and `INTERNAL://DEFAULT` in the NodeMCU flasher.

This booted the new NodeMCU firmware, all my files were gone and I'm out of infinite reboot loop.

Comment: There is a problem with nodemcu not clearing the ram properly.  This is what causes the infinite reboot.

Comment: Writing this as of Jan 2016 - the above problem still exists in NodeMCU and the above solution still works.

Comment: Where did you find those addresses (0x7e000 and 0x7c000) - is there a doc I find more on these?

Comment: You can refer memory map here: https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Memory-Map

The addresses may change based on your flash size.

Answer (score 5):

Flash the following files:

0x00000.bin to 0x00000

0x10000.bin to 0x10000

And, the address for esp_init_data_default.bin depends on the size of your module's flash.

0x7c000 for 512 kB, modules like ESP-01, -03, -07 etc.

0xfc000 for 1 MB, modules like ESP8285, PSF-A85

0x1fc000 for 2 MB

0x3fc000 for 4 MB, modules like ESP-12E, NodeMCU devkit 1.0, WeMos D1 mini

Then, after flashing those binaries format its file system (run "file.format()" using [ESPlorer](http://esp8266.ru/esplorer-latest/?f=ESPlorer.zip)) before flashing any other binaries.

[Downloads Link](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher/tree/master/Resources/Binaries)

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished working through a similar problem.  In my case it was end-user error that caused a need to forcibly wipe `init.lua`, but I think both problems could be solved similarly.  (For completeness, my problem was putting a far-too-short `dsleep()` call in `init.lua`, leaving the board resetting itself immediately upon starting `init.lua`.)

I tried flashing new NodeMCU firmware, writing `blank.bin` and `esp_init_data_default.bin` to `0x7E000` and `0x7C000`, and also writing `0x00000.bin` to `0x00000` and `0x10000.bin` to `0x10000`.  None of these things helped in my case.

My hardware is an Adafruit Huzzah ESP8266 breakout (ESP-12), with 4MB of flash.

What worked for me was:

1. Download the NONOS SDK from Espressif (I used version 1.5.2 from http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1702).
2. Unzip it to get at `boot_v1.2.bin`, `user1.1024.new.2.bin`, `blank.bin`, and `esp_init_data_default.bin` (under bin/ and bin/at/).
3. Flash the following files to the specified memory locations:

   1. `boot_v1.2.bin` to `0x00000`
   2. `user1.1024.new.2.bin` to `0x010000`
   3. `esp_init_data_default.bin` to `0xfc000`
   4. `blank.bin` to `0x7e000`
   5. Note about flashing:

      - I used `esptool.py` 1.2.1.
      - Because of the nature of my problem, I was only able to write changes to the flash when in programming mode (i.e. after booting with GPIO0 held down to GND).
      - I found that I needed to reset the board between each step (else invocations of `esptool.py` after the first would fail).
4. Erased the flash.  `esptool.py --port <your/port> erase_flash`
5. Then I was able to write a new firmware.  I used a stock nodeMCU 0.9.5 just to isolate variables, but I strongly suspect any firmware would work at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The only think that worked for me was python flash tool esptool in ubuntu, windows flashtool never deleted init.lua and reboot loop.

Commands (ubuntu):

```
git clone https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool.git
cd esptool
python esptool.py -h
ls -l /dev/tty*
```

nodemcu_latest.bin can be downloaded from github or anywhere.

```
sudo python esptool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 --baud 460800 write_flash --flash_size=8m 0 nodemcu_latest.bin
```