# How to recover nodemcu infinite loop

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I made a mistake loading init.lua with a infinite loop on my nodemcu/ESP8266 board.

Then the board keep rebooting without any other instruction executed.

```
i = 10
timerId = 0
timerDelay = 30000 -- Milisec
pin = 5
gpio.mode(pin,gpio.INPUT) 
repeat(    
    print(gpio.read(pin))
    i = i + 1
    end)
until i < 5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover from infinite reboot loops in NodeMCU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721859/how-to-recover-from-infinite-reboot-loops-in-nodemcu) None of the answers here helped me. Linked question's answer did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried flashing the board

```
python esptool.py -p /dev/tty.wchusbserial1450 run

python esptool.py -p /dev/tty.wchusbserial1450 write_flash 0x0000 ../nodemcu_latest.bin
```

And after that fix my code and load it again and now works fine

Comment: Always test code in a file named something other than init.lua for this very reason.

Comment: +1 to last comment.  Put a tmr.alarm() one-shot to kick off your app after a 2-3 sec delay.  in your `init.lua`. This is long enough to send a file.remove() to delte the init.lua file if you are stuck in a panic loop.

Comment: @jezuz, what is the first line for with the `run` command? I did only the `write_flash` command and got the result I was looking for.

Comment: I found using the flasher tool PyFlash, with the "clear flash" option, did this.

Comment: I had to do `erase_flash` before writing back the flash to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
--This file is init.lua
local IDLE_AT_STARTUP_MS = 10000;

tmr.alarm(1,IDLE_AT_STARTUP_MS,0,function()
    dofile("program.lua")--Write your program name in dofile
end)
```

I do use this strategy in order to prevent infinite loop at the startups when bug occurs. Save this file as init.lua and write your programs into the program.lua

Answer (score 1):

What I do is use ESPlorer (Java app) http://esp8266.ru/esplorer/#download

While I am mucking around I just have my `init.lua` file called `init1.lua`, if the ESP reboots its no problem you just click on `init1.lua` button that is displayed on the right hand side ( after you use the "Reload" button to display the file system contents)

Nice and easy, when your done you can right click on the file to rename it back to `init.lua`.

Answer (score 0):

There's isn't an elegant way to recover.

The best thing to do is build in a way to get prevent your code from stating in an emergency.  For example, as TerryE suggests, set a one-shot timer using `timer.alarm` in `init.lua` to call your main code with a long enough delay that you can call `timer.stop` in the case that you don't want to boot into your main code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was stuck in a `while` loop.

Flashing a different firmware worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is basically same as [researcher01's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36141156/2251364) but uses [OO API timers](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/tmr/) as the one used above is removed in 2019.

```lua
--This file is init.lua
local IDLE_AT_STARTUP_MS = 10000;

tmr.create():alarm(IDLE_AT_STARTUP_MS, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE,function()
    dofile("program.lua")--Write your program name in dofile
end)
```